# Dynamic content type validation for paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, content-type

Here is my Rail4 app: the app will have many services, and each service may have many submissions. A submission can be either a picture, or a word file, or a pdf file. However, the content type of a submission is really defined by the service object.

I understand there is a validates_attachment_content_type function, but the question is how can I dynamically change the content_type according to the service object?

Here is the code for my project:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_acccessor :service_content_type
  has_many :submissions
end

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service

  has_attached_file :attachment
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, 
    :content_type => self.service.service_content_type # THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that the validation is declared in the class context. `self` here refers to the class, not the instance, so calling `self.service` would raise an error since `service` is an instance method.

ActiveModel validations usually let you pass in a lambda block in which you can use the instance to determine validity. But the [Paperclip doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/ClassMethods:validates_attachment_content_type) says `validates_attachment_content_type` only lets you pass in a String, Regexp, or an Array containing elements of the those two types.

You can use a custom validation method to make sure your `attachment_content_type` column is the right value. But I'm not 100% sure if this offers the same security as `validates_attachment_content_type`.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service

  has_attached_file :attachment

  validate :validate_content_type

  def validate_content_type
    unless attachment_content_type == service.service_content_type
      errors.add(:attachment_content_type, "must be #{service.service_content_type}")
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can use a built-in Rails validation with a lambda but have less control over the error message:

```
  validates :attachment_content_type,
    inclusion: { in: ->(submission) { [submission.service.service_content_type] } }
```

Comment: For Paperclip 5.0 I need validates_attachment_content_type, but my content_types are in the database for each site, so I'd like to pass in self.IMAGE_VIDEO_AUDIO_FILE_CONTENT_TYPES ... but I'm not sure how do to this...

Answer (score 0):

`self.service.service_content_type` has to be regex, which I am guessing isn't. Read [doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/ClassMethods:validates_attachment_content_type)

Comment: Not true. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to access this with:

`validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => @service.service_content_type`

It worked for me in the following context (which is an array and not an "object", but I imagine it should translate):

`validates_attachment_content_type :detail, :content_type => @IMAGE_VIDEO_AUDIO_FILE_CONTENT_TYPES`